# Treeview from sql table

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, treeview

I have sql table like below. I have to show it in tree view

```
id   parentid     name
1     NULL       outlook
2     1      overcast
3     1       rainy
4     1       sunny
5     2        yes
6     3        wind
7     4      humidity
8     6       strong
9     6        weak
10    7        high
11    8         no
12    9         yes
13   10          no
14   15         yes
15   7        normal
```

I want output as

-outlook

```
 - overcast

         - yes

- rainy
     - wind
        - strong
              - no
        - weak
              - yes
-sunny
   - humidity

         -high
               -no
         -normal
               -yes
```

There is only one root node 'outlook' here.then comes child nodes and sub-child nodes like that.

Comment: The purpose of a tree view is to show the child nodes **only** when the user expands the parent node. In other words, you should simply load the immediate children when parent is expanded. Trying to load all tree at startup is a bad design idea. This table is small, so not a big problem here, but imagine it is huge. Why would you force your users to wait for a full tree to load?

Comment: @Jose Rui Santos                                                       sir,i am a beginner in asp.net.we can go for node expansion when it is selected ....but i don't know how to do...

Comment: @Dhany; please change this line with this one ds.Relations.Add("Children", dtbl1.Columns["Id"], dtbl1.Columns["ParentId"]);

Comment: my answer from a while ago might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948592/populating-treeview-using-linq/948790#948790

Comment: @CRice: In that code,how i will pass the table data.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH    q AS 
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   ParentID IS NULL -- this condition defines the ultimate ancestors in your chain, change it as appropriate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  m.*
        FROM    mytable m
        JOIN    q
        ON      m.parentID = q.ID
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in your aspx or ascx file:

```
<asp:Treeview ID="TreeView1" runat="server" />
```

And in the codebehind to populate it:

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); //(populate the dataset with the table)

    //Use LINQ to filter out items without a parent
    DataTable parents = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
        .Where(i => i.Field<object>("parentid") == DBNull.Value)
        .CopyToDataTable();

    //Use LINQ to filter out items with parent
    DataTable children = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
        .Where(i => i.Field<object>("parentid") != DBNull.Value)
        .OrderBy(i => i.Field<int>("parentid"))
        .CopyToDataTable();

    //Add the parents to the treeview
    foreach(DataRow dr in parents)
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
        node.Text = dr["name"].ToString();
        node.Value = dr["id"].ToString();
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
    }

    //Add the children to the parents
    foreach(DataRow dr in children)
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
        node.Text = dr["name"].ToString();
        node.Value = dr["id"].ToString();
        TreeNode parentNode = FindNodeByValue(dr["parentid"].ToString());
        if(parentNode != null)
            parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
    }
}

private TreeNode FindNodeByValue(string value)
{
    foreach(TreeNode node in TreeView1.Nodes)
    {
        if(node.Value = value) return node;
        TreeNode pnode = FindNodeRecursion(node, value);
        if(pnode != null) return pnode;
    }
    return null;
}

private TreeNode FindNodeRecursion(TreeNode parentNode, string value)
{
    foreach(TreeNode node in parentNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        if(node.Value = value) return node;
        TreeNode pnode = FindNodeRecursion(node, value);
        if(pnode != null) return pnode;
    }
    return null;
}
```

There might be a better way to do this and I haven't tested it, but it should work.  Or you could always try out [Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) or another third party tool that makes data binding for these types of controls super easy.