# Create treeview from SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, treeview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Treeview from sql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744186/treeview-from-sql-table)

I am having SQL table like below with three columns id,parentid and name.. I have to show it in tree view:

```
id   parentid    name
1     NULL      outlook
2     1      overcast
3     1       rainy
4     1       sunny
5     2        yes
6     3        wind
7     4      humidity
8     6       strong
9     6        weak
10    7        high
11    8         no
12    9         yes
13   10          no
14   15         yes
15   7        normal
```

Please help me if any one knows....

I want output as

- outlook

  ```
  - overcast

           - yes

  - rainy
         - wind
              - strong
                    - no
              - weak
                    - yes
  -sunny
         - humidity

               -high
                     -no
               -normal
                     -yes
  ```

There is only one root node.then comes child nodes and sub-child nodes like that..

Comment: one aspect of Stack Overflow is that once you post a question, if you have additional information, you can edit your original question.  Opening a new one that is identical to your first is considered bad form.

Answer (score 0):

Write a program to read from table construct a n-ary tree and print in pre-order traversal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of rows you could just iterate through the collection and recursively add each item to your tree view.